# How to write a plot title in more than one line using suptitle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is an example:

```
fig.suptitle('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit donec nec condimentum libero. Phasellus condimentum porttitor congue morbi eget quam sed justo egestas lobortis aenean et erat metus')
```

How to make this title in 3 lines?

Comment: what do you mean by make this title in 3 lines? Do you want to write the string in source code in 3 lines or divide it to 3 lines for output?

Comment: Does it not work to simply add inn newline characters(\n) in the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split title of a figure in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598163/split-title-of-a-figure-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just insert a newline character `\n` where you want the new line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('This sentence is\nbeing split\ninto three lines')
plt.show()
```