# Split matplotlib title with different formatting for each level

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to make a matplotlib plot that has four levels of a title all with different formatting specifications for each level.

I read this similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598163/split-title-of-a-figure-in-matplotlib) which helps with adding multilevel titles. However, I am still unsure of how to make them each different colors for example. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

```
ax.set_title('Normalized occupied \n Neighbors')
```

\n adds the level but cannot make 'Normalized occupied' black color and 'Neigbors' blue.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question completely. However, a little bit more complex than I had anticipated. Nevertheless, thank you for your response.

Comment: I have tried to further reduce the complexity. Check the edit. It took some time to adapt it to your desired output but glad to know it answered your question

Comment: One further follow up, if we wanted to have both color and size differing, would size just be inputed as an array as well?

Comment: It is possible. I have added a very simple version without any function now to my answer. Check the edit.

Comment: Just saw the edit - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a solution based on [this official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html). As you can see, the solution is *not general* but works for your particular example.

The only problem specific thing here is `x_pos = [0.3, 0.4]` because you would like to align the sub-titles in the center. If you remove `x_pos` and just use 0.5, you will see that the code still works but the alignment is kind of left aligned. Here I use `y=1.2` to specify the starting position of the title in relative coordinates. `y=0` means the lower x-axis and `y=1` means the upper x-axis.

I simplified several lines to reduce the complexity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rainbow_title(x_pos, y, strings, colors, ax=None, **kw):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    for x, s, c in zip(x_pos, strings, colors):
        text = ax.text(x, y, s + " ", color=c,  **kw)
        y *= 0.9

x_pos = [0.3, 0.4]        
rainbow_title(x_pos, 1.2, "Normalized occupied\n Neighbors".split('\n'), 
              ['black', 'blue'], size=18)
```

[image]

**Simplified version with changing fontsize**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

title = "Normalized occupied\n Neighbors"
x_pos = [0.3, 0.4]  
sizes = [18, 14]
colors = ['black', 'blue']
y = 1.2

for x, s, c, size in zip(x_pos, title.split('\n'), colors, sizes):
    text = ax.text(x, y, s + " ", color=c,  size=size)
    y *= 0.9
```

[image]